# How can I extract the timestamp from the end of a shell variable when the format isn't fixed?

Tags: regex, perl, shell, awk

I'm trying to extract the timestamp from the end of a shell variable like this:

```
Input=AEXP_CSTONE_EU_prpbdp_sourcefile_yyyymmddhhmmss.txt
TimeStamp=`echo $Input | awk -F"_" '{print $6}'`
```

This works for this particular case, but the format of the string can change. For example, it could also be:

```
Input=AEXP_CSTONE_EU_prpbdp_sourcefile_prospects_yyyymmddhhmmss.txt
```

The variable will always end with `yyyymmddhhmmss.txt`. How can I extract the timestamp consistently?

Comment: You say "...this yyyymmddhhmmss.txt remaining format may change" and then "This part (yyyymmddhhmmss.txt) will never change." Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I tried to say "except this part (yyyymmddhhmmss.txt) remaining format may change".                                     For ex: AEXP_CSTONE_EU_prpbdp_sourcefile_yyyymmddhhmmss.txt may change to  AEXP_CSTONE_EU_prpbdp_sourcefile_prospects_yyyymmddhhmmss.txt

Comment: `$ perl -e 'print $1 if $ARGV[0] =~ /_(\d{14})\.txt$/' AEXP_CSTONE_EU_prpbdp_sourcefile_20151116143925.txt`

Comment: Works fine .. Thanq Matt

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ echo $Input
AEXP_CSTONE_EU_prpbdp_sourcefile_prospects_20151116141111.txt
```

You can use `sed`:

```
$ echo $Input | sed -n 's|.*_\([0-9]\{14\}\)\.txt|\1|p' 
20151116141111
```

Or nested grep:

```
$ echo $Input | grep -Eo '_[0-9]{14}\.txt' | grep -Eo '[0-9]{14}'
20151116141111
```

awk:

```
$ echo $Input | awk -F_ '{split($NF, a, "."); print a[1]}'
20151116141111
```

Perl

```
$ echo $Input | perl -ne 'print $1 if /_(\d{14})\.txt/'
20151116141111
```

cut and rev:

```
$ echo $Input | rev | cut -d'_' -f 1 | rev | cut -d'.' -f 1
20151116141111
```

Bash:

```
$ last=${Input##*_}
$ echo $last
20151116141111.txt
$ ts=${last%.*}
$ echo $ts
20151116141111
```

In summary, lots of ways...

---

If you don't want to loose the `.txt` part, even easier:

```
$ echo $Input | sed -n 's|.*_\([0-9]\{14\}\.txt\)|\1|p'
20151116141111.txt
$ echo $Input | grep -Eo '[0-9]{14}\.txt$'
20151116141111.txt
$ echo $Input | awk -F_ '{print $NF}'
20151116141111.txt
$ echo $Input | perl -ne 'print $1 if /_(\d{14}\.txt)/'
20151116141111.txt
$ echo $Input | rev | cut -d'_' -f 1 | rev
20151116141111.txt
$ last=${Input##*_}
$ echo $last
20151116141111.txt
```

Comment: Thanks much dawg.. Each and every solution worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the part that will *not* change then:

```
TimeStamp=$(echo $Input | perl -pe 's/.*(\d{14})\.txt/$1/')
```

Comment: Escape the `.` like `s/.*(\d{14})\.txt/$1/` otherwise the `.` has the metacharacter meaning of any character.

Comment: @dawg Good catch. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You are extracting the 6th field separated by `_`, yet it seems you really want to extract the last field. You can do that with parameter expansion:

```
timestamp=${Input##*_}
timestamp=${timestamp%.txt}
```

See [BashFAQ 100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for more on string manipulation in bash.

In awk, you'd use `$NF` to reference the last field, though awk is overkill for this.